# Websocket events are not called inside tasks.py

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, celery, django-channels

I use Scheduled Celery workers to perform a loop of sending WebSocket events, but it doesn't seem to work inside tasks.py.

I tested inside views.py and that seems to work, but I need to send them in tasks.py, does anyone has any fix for this?

consumers.py

```py
class RouletteConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_group_name = 'roulette'
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name, 
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.accept()

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'type':'connection_established',
            'message': "Working"
        }))

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        bet_data = text_data_json['bet_data']

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type':'send_bet',
                'bet_data': bet_data,
            }
        )

    def send_bet(self, event):
        print("EVENT TRIGGERED")
        bet_data = event['bet_data']
        
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'type':'bet',
            'bet_data': bet_data
        }))

    def current_state(self, event,  type='current_state'):
        print("EVENT TRIGGERED")
        message = event['message']

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'type':'state',
            'current_state': message
        }))
```

tasks.py

```py
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

@app.task
def change_state(*args, **kwargs):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        'roulette',
        {
            'type': 'current_state',
            'message': "EVENT TRIGGERED"
        }
    )
```